# How to display only different values between two records?

Tags: jquery, mysql

Suppose we have this table:

```
ID_office     Status    Name       PERSONS
114574        ON        Danubius   51
118451        OFF       Osiride    51
```

How can I extract only the different values ​​for id_office?

I would like to get this result:

```
ID_office     Status    Name     
114574        ON        Danubius   
118451        OFF       Osiride
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line to your query

```
SELECT ID_OFFICE,STATUS,NAME FROM your_table_name
```

Comment: the problem is to extract only the different fields and not the same ones.
Otherwise the query would be too simple if we think we have a big table

Answer (score 0):

This will give you only the different values for each record (Office and Status):

`` SELECT ID_office, `Status Name` FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID_office, `Status Name`; ``